# PHP variable in loop

Tags: php, variables, loops, for-loop

I have the following:

```
$textq1 = 'text';
$textq2 = 'more text';
```

I have a loop:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 70; $i++) {

    echo "<div>". $textq1." ";

}
```

Now....what I'd like to do is, within the loop have the `1` part of the `$textq1` be the value of `$i`.

Is that possible?

Comment: Would be a whole lot easier if you had $textq = array('text','more text'); rather than $textq1 = 'text'; $textq2 = 'more text';

Comment: @MarkBaker - yep, sure would be easier in an array but I've inherited a whole host of code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
echo "<div>". $textq1." ";
```

To:

```
echo "<div>". ${'textq'.$i} ." ";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (...)
{
    echo "<div>{${textq$i}}</div>";
}
```

Comment: That would result in `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE` error.

Comment: Yes it would. Would work if it were `echo "<div>{${"textq$i"}}</div>";` (need quotes around the variable name).

Answer (score 1):

```
$var = "textq{$i}";
echo "<div>". $$var." ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example about `variable variables` in the PHP docs:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php#105282